# Can I pre-load an image for use in TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am working with a large amount of pages (letters) that are the same except for the address and a few other minor details. I believe what slows the PDF creation down the most is the logo image that I'm including on every page (even though it is fairly small).

I'm hoping to speed up the process some more by caching the logo, i.e. by loading the file once and storing it in a variable and have TCPDF use that instead of loading the image every time. TCPDF can load a "PHP image data stream", and the example given is this:

```
$imgdata = base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDrEX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
$pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata);
```

However, I have no idea how to create an image stream like this from a file.

My logo is a small (4kB) PNG file. If I use `readfile($file)` and send that to `$pdf->Image` with the '@' in front, it errors out - something about the cache folder which is already set to chmod 777 (it's a test server - I'll work on proper permissions on the live server). I believe I also tried `base64_encode` which also didn't work.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

PS: I already noticed that the more pages I include into the PDF, the slower it gets, so I'll find a good middle (probably 200-250 pages per file instead of the current 500).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted the same question in the TCPDF forum on sourceforge ([sourceforge forum post](https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/3674b3fb/)), and the author of TCPDF answered.

He said that images are cached internally, however if the images need processing, he suggests using the `XObject()` template system (see [example 62](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_062.phps) on TCPDF site).

It took me a while to get it working (still not sure why it didn't work for me at first), but once I had it looking exactly like my original version using `Image()`, I ran a few tests with about 3,000 entries divided into PDF files of 500 pages each.

There was no speed gain at all between `XObject()` and `Image()`, and `XObject()` actually appeared to make the resulting files just a tiny bit larger (2.5kB in a 1.2MB file).

While this doesn't directly answer my original question (how to create a PHP data stream that can be directly used in TCPDF using `Image('@'.$image)`), it tells me what I really needed to know - the image is already cached, and caching using `XObject()` does not provide any advantage to my situation.